# Rails 7 - javascript importmap tags - custom for logged and nologged users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-maps

I think how to add custom application.js file for logged and nologged users i Rails 7 app with javascript_importmap_tags

It would be nice if there was an option to put the file name in the tag

```
<% javascript_importmap_tags 'filename' %>
```

but it is impossible. So how to attach another **application.js** file for users logged in **Rails 7 with device gem** ( application.html.erb and home.html.erb for logged user )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace `application.js` with the "name" of your pinned file:

```rb
<%= javascript_importmap_tags "name" %>
```

To load another file in addition to `application.js`:

```rb
<% if current_user %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "account" %>
<% end %>
```

To do this from a template:

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "account" %>
<% end %>

# app/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  # ...
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

---

**Update**

Any logic you want to apply here, you can just split `javascript_importmap_tags`:

```rb
<%= javascript_inline_importmap_tag %>
<%= javascript_importmap_module_preload_tags %>
<%= javascript_importmap_shim_nonce_configuration_tag %>
<%= javascript_importmap_shim_tag %>
<%= javascript_import_module_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "nologged". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @Wordica you have to add a pin for "nologged" file

Comment: it load application.js and nologged.js ---  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-4b4b4ab05ab2b6888bd38eda141783ef44d71d19279f54d8b1791da6d9bb8833.js","nologged": "/assets/nologged-c5c89eb22ed0f045ad4f4ce3bd9a41f11e868623e693ac241c793790a95dee58.js",

Comment: @Wordica isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: no ... I wanted load application.js for logged user and nologged for not logged users ... anyway, I solved the problem by checking if a given "div" exists (for logged-in users it does not exist) ... but I'm extending the topic because maybe someone knows how to limit redundant JS - for efficiency.

Comment: @Wordica why can't you load `javascript_importmap_tags` for logged in users and `javascript_importmap_tags "nologged"` for not logged in users.

Comment: I try to ... I add standard javascript_importmap_tags in view for logged users ( application.html.erb ) and javascript_importmap_tags 'nologged' for nologged ( home.html.erb ... but I see what I see in source, rails always import also application.js ... right now I just add condition in application.js and if div from nologged html exist I just do not import some custom JS file.

Comment: @Wordica oh you mean it's loading the file, that's because  of `preload: true` in importmap.rb. but it doesn't import it. just remove `preload` option.